# spotlight is always on and switch is not working

Tags: electrical

I have a spotlight outside all the wires are tracked and in working order but the light stays on constantly .even when connected to its switch. this one is a head scratcher. I replaced the light switch too.

Comment: Can you provide some pictures and/or a wiring diagram, "as wired"?

Comment: i don't know how to upload pictures but anyway I disconnected the switch and put the breaker back on and the light remains on.

Comment: It IS unfortunate that I can't even manage to find a clear description of how to post a picture on the site (and I already know how, and had managed to find one a while back to point someone at.) Basically you click on the little blue-green rectangle up top while in edit mode, and upload from your computer. Here one is: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-can-i-add-an-image-to-a-question-answer

Answer (score 1):

If we eliminate "magic" as an option, the only thing that makes sense here is that you have not, in fact tracked all the wires properly (or at least they are not connected the way they should be.)

If you disconnect and insulate the wires connected to the switch (circuit breaker off, of course) does the light still come on? If so, then you don't have **two** defective switches (which is pretty unlikely anyway) – you have a wiring error.

Answer (score 0):

If you disconnected the switch and left the wires hanging and the breaker turned the light on, that switch is connected to something else. Does this light have two switches aka 3 way switch? IOW does the suspect switch have 3 wires or two wires connected to it. (ignore the green wire which may be connected to the frame of the switch in this count) Is there a red wire?

If you connected the wires together without the switch you haven't learned anything. Leave them hanging (if you try this it would be a good idea to turn the breaker off verify the wires are in fact dead and put some wire nuts or electrical tape on the ends while you're diagnosing)

This doesn't sound like you're problem but a light or motion sensor could fail to always on.